# Why file command report dynamic linked with gcc -static

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, alpine-linux

```
gcc -static -g -O2 -static -o init init-init.o 
file init
# init: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, with debug_info, not stripped
ldd init
#    ldd (0x7fd49e2ed000)
```

**objdump -p init**

```
init:     file format elf64-x86-64

Program Header:
    LOAD off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**21
        filesz 0x00000000000076e4 memsz 0x00000000000076e4 flags r-x
    LOAD off    0x0000000000007e30 vaddr 0x0000000000207e30 paddr 0x0000000000207e30 align 2**21
        filesz 0x00000000000002d8 memsz 0x0000000000001488 flags rw-
DYNAMIC off    0x0000000000007e60 vaddr 0x0000000000207e60 paddr 0x0000000000207e60 align 2**3
        filesz 0x0000000000000150 memsz 0x0000000000000150 flags rw-
STACK off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**4
        filesz 0x0000000000000000 memsz 0x0000000000000000 flags rw-
RELRO off    0x0000000000007e30 vaddr 0x0000000000207e30 paddr 0x0000000000207e30 align 2**0
        filesz 0x00000000000001d0 memsz 0x00000000000001d0 flags r--

Dynamic Section:
SYMBOLIC             0x0000000000000000
INIT                 0x00000000000002c0
FINI                 0x0000000000006473
GNU_HASH             0x0000000000000158
STRTAB               0x00000000000001b0
SYMTAB               0x0000000000000180
STRSZ                0x0000000000000007
SYMENT               0x0000000000000018
DEBUG                0x0000000000000000
PLTGOT               0x0000000000207fb0
RELA                 0x00000000000001b8
RELASZ               0x0000000000000108
RELAENT              0x0000000000000018
BIND_NOW             0x0000000000000000
FLAGS_1              0x0000000008000001
RELACOUNT            0x000000000000000b
```

**readelf init -h**

```
ELF Header:
Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Class:                             ELF64
Data:                              2's complement, little endian
Version:                           1 (current)
OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
ABI Version:                       0
Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
Version:                           0x1
Entry point address:               0x1158
Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
Start of section headers:          308248 (bytes into file)
Flags:                             0x0
```

Why `Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)` ?

Trying to compile [supermin](https://github.com/libguestfs/supermin) under alpine, but [src/Makefile.am#L159](https://github.com/libguestfs/supermin/blob/master/src/Makefile.am#L159)
require `init` is static linked by `file` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ET_DYN` is used for position-independent executables (PIE), whether they are statically linked or not.  The lack of a program interpreter and `DT_NEEDED` entries in the dynamic section indicate that the program is indeed statically linked.  You can check that using `readelf -l` (no `.interp`) and `readelf -d` (no `NEEDED`).

Running the program under `strace` will also verify that no shared objects are loaded at program start.

Comment: So the `file` command report only ET_DYN, not check DT_NEEDED ?

Comment: Apparently. Statically linked PIE binaries are a fairly recent innovation.

Comment: So, this is a feature/bug for file ?